# Java loops with math symbols

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make a loop that it will print the msg "Hello World" with these functions.

```
void functionA(int n); // log(n) 
void functionB(int n); // sqrt(n) 
void functionC(int n); // n 
void functionD(int n); // n log(n) 
void functionE(int n); // n²
void functionF(int n); // n³
void functionG(int n); // 2^n
void functionH(int n); // n!
```

I made this but something is wrong.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    public static double log10(double n)

    {   
        double n;

        for(n = 0; n <= Math.log10(double n); n++)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: You seem to have a poor grasp of basic Java syntax.  You cannot declare `log10(double n)` inside `main()` that way, nor can you declare `n` inside a call to `Math.log10()`.  I would suggest looking at some of the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) available from oracle.

Comment: this code doesn't even compile in few places. For sure you have main method definition not closed and you define variable n twice in log10 method.

Comment: You need to put more details about what "is wrong". For example, are you getting an exception or other form of error? Are you getting any output at all. What are your expected results and how do they compare to your actual results?

Comment: I don't know why such users exist. They post a bad question here and depart from this world for eternity without saying another word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could make out of your question, I took your code made it compile and modified it:

```
public class test
{
    public static void functionC(int n)
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        functionC(5);
    }
}
```

This would be functionC. For the other functions you need to modify the argument "n" within each method in order to achieve the correct result (raise to power etc.).

I will echo what Azurefrog mentioned:
You need to read up on the basics of the Java syntax because your code had a lot of errors and did not compile. Some of the errors: for loop, declaration of methods and classes, locality of arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really need to read up on the basics!